# How to only allow a certain number of io exceptions?

Tags: java, ioexception

I'm wondering if there is a good and standard way to only allow a certain number of IO exceptions (connection timeout etc.) before you stop trying and maybe send an automated email to let someone know there's a problem. I can think of an ugly way to do it with a try catch block that keeps a counter and checks the value of that counter before the try. Is there a more standard nicer way to implement that?

Comment: Please add a language tag to your question.

Comment: Right thanks sorry!

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/10947933/3260495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an ìnt` variable that acts as a counter:

```
int counter = 0;
while (true){
    try{
        // do something
        break;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        counter++;

        if (counter >= 10)
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

It will catch the exception, print the stacktrace and only rethrow the exception if the counter exceeds 10. The email sending part will be more difficult for several reasons:

- You need a library do send emails (AFAIK)
- You need to configure the email server
- You need to authenticate against the server (The user either needs to supply a password or you need to hardcode the password --> bad practice)
- A possible reason for the IOException might be that the machine is not connected to the internet. Sending emails will fail in that case too.

Comment: Ok yeah I thought about doing something like this, I just thought there might a different, more (professional?) way (because this is the sorta thing I would wrote in my first java class). I guess the basics do work tho. Thanks!

Comment: If it worked for you, consider marking it as the solution. Thx :-)

Comment: If you want to use this code block in many places, I suggest you wrap the counter logic into a separate static method in some common class.

Comment: I am not a fan of static things where they don't need to be static, but you could make the code more abstract if you'd wrap it in a method and supply a `Runnable` which contains the actual logic