# How to handle exceptions in Spring that are not thrown not on controller level?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

My app has a scheduler job that gets some data from the database and then sends a POST request to another server. I need to handle some exceptions, but I cannot use @ControllerAdvice or @ExceptionHandler as there is no controller involved. What's the way to handle exceptions in this case?

Comment: The simplest way is of course to wrap the method that might throw an exception with a `try { ... } catch (...) { ... }` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own `@Advice` to catch all exception.

Check this already answered by @eric-b [AOP Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947933/aop-exception-handling)